# Setting a cookie with jquery cookie.js using toggleClass

Tags: jquery, cookies, closest, toggleclass

I have the following html for a group of thumbnails and I use an icon (icon-heart) to set a favorite for an image by changing the color of the icon to red and adding a class="Favorite":

```
 <div class="selectFav">
 <a href="slide.jpg" data-rel="prettyPhoto[Gallery]"  title="Slide"><img  src="slide.jpg" alt="Slide"  width="124" height="124"/></a>
 <ul class="icon">
 <li>   <div class="icon-heart"></div> </li>
 <li>   <div class="icon-camera"></div> </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
 .flag{
 color:red;
 }
```

I want to set a cookie using query cookie.js when the individual thumb is set as a favorite. The problem is that when I try to set a cookie, I set all icon-heart icons to show as a favorite rather than just the one for that particular selectFav

```
$(".icon-heart").on('click', function() {
$(this).toggleClass('flag').closest('.selectFav').addClass('Favorite');
});
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: why you need the cookie? maybe an ajax post will be good when clicking this as favorite, or you want to hide the heart icon?

Comment: I want returning visitors to still see their saved favorites on the page, of course. The heart icon changes color, hiding it defeats the purpose and does not allow them to come back and select that image in the future as a favorite if it is hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this for you as an example:

**Live Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/GUUjr/1/

- This will help you in order to know how to manage cookies.

**Instructions:**

- Just `click` the hearts you want in a first moment (those hearts will dissapear) then click `Run` button the times as you want and look that the previous hearts still dissapeared cause of the cookie.
- You can click the `Kill the cookie` button to start everything again. Please read code comments for better understanding.

Comment: Thanks so much for your effort! Unfortunately, i can't have the icons disappear. Mostly it means once one makes the favorite selection, they can never change it unless they kill the cookie. There is no way to toggle easily. here is a jsfiddle to show you how it works in my gallery. [http://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/6MKeg/](http://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/6MKeg/)

Comment: Looking forward to seeing it.

Comment: I updated my jsfiddle with your code altered to fit my html. It works if just one heart or all hearts are selected but if I select 2 out of 3, it randomly sets the favorite in the cookie. Any ideas why this happens? My novice abilities don't quite see why

Comment: Oscar, Any chance you might be able to update your answer? Would appreciate it!

Comment: Hey! sorry for not answering on time, I was really busy, today I will take a moment to help you in the morning :-)

Comment: Hey Oscar, If you get some time to follow up in the future, it would be great! Mike I understand if your busy!

Comment: Sorry, I got lots of things to do and I was just answering fast questions but I really promise that tomorrow will focus on this and let you know something, whats your time? just to know

Comment: take all the time you need. I appreciate any help and no time restraint.